# Need help simulating this scroll-fade jQuery effect

Tags: jquery, css

i was in wondering if anybody out there who is far smarter than me is able to indentify how to recreate this effect. This is the link to the site http://www.acendor.com/demo/products.html.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a plugin like http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/ or http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/